# SQL Server: fetching by date range returns error

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, stored-procedures, dynamic

I have a dynamic stored procedure that includes the following input variables and Where condition with the column R.dateRec being formatted as datetime.

```
@rangeStart datetime,
@rangeEnd datetime

AND   R.dateRec BETWEEN ' + @rangeStart + ' AND ' + @rangeEnd + '
```

When I run the procedure without this condition than it works well but when adding this it returns the following error, maybe because it doesn't recognise the values as dates:

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Can someone tell me how I can prevent this from happening ? The column in question only contains valid dates (no blank or NULL values).

Many thanks in advance, Tim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

need to convert the date parameters to varchar first if it is a dynamic sql...

added quotes

```
{beginning of query...} + ' and R.dateRec between ''' + convert(varchar, @rangeStart, 111) + ''' and ''' + convert(varchar, @rangeEnd, 111) + ''' {continue query}'
```

Comment: Thanks. It's a dynamic procedure so I cant keep it like that.

Comment: Thanks for the update - this works perfect ! SQL sometimes can be picky. :)

Answer (score 0):

are you missing quotes?  i.e.

```
   AND   R.dateRec BETWEEN ''' + @rangeStart + ''' AND ''' + @rangeEnd + '''
```

Comment: Thanks. That didn't work but the solution from krawl resolved it.